# Selecting individual letters in .print with Raphael 2.1

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I tried to do what this Raphael tutorial [ http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/raphael/intro/ ] does and select individual letters from a string printed with .print, but no joy

I have generated the font with cufon, and replaced Cufon.registerFont with Raphael.registerFont

```
var paper = Raphael( '#div', 500, 500 ),
    label = paper.print( xCenter, yCenter, 'blah',  paper.getFont("CelliniProMedium"), 54 );

label[1].attr( 'fill', 'red');
```

causes an error because label is just a path not an array of paths. 
What gives?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is definitely a change in behavior between 1.4 and 2.0 -- and it's a bit of functionality that came in handy in more than one situation.

On the other hand, replicating the array result functionality is easy to do by extending Raphael 2.0...

```
Raphael.fn.printArray = function printArray( x, y, string, font, size, letter_spacing, line_height )
{
    var result = [];
    var cx = x, cy = y;        
    size = size || 16;
    letter_spacing = letter_spacing || 0.2;
    line_height = line_height || 1.5;        
    for ( var i = 0; i < string.length; i++ )
    {
        if ( string[i] == " " )
        {
            cx += size;
            continue;
        }
        else if ( string[i] == "\n" )
        {
            cx = x;
            cy += size * line_height;
            continue;
        }
        var glyph = this.print( 0, 0, string[i], font, size ).attr( { opacity: 0 } );
        var glyphBox = glyph.getBBox();
        glyph.attr( { transform: "T" + cx + "," + cy, opacity: 1 } );
        cx += glyphBox.width + ( size * letter_spacing );
        result.push( glyph );
    }
    return result;
}
```

This isn't perfect code, but with a little refinement it could easily fill the gap.

Answer (score 0):

so it looks like it's either a bug or a feature with 2.1 - I got 1.4 from GitHub and it works as expected. Leaving question open for a short while in case anyone can shed any more lights on this, as I think it may be useful to others.